# How do I script codesign to trust an imported keychain from the Mac command line

Tags: macos, shell, command-line, code-signing, keychain

Hi I am trying to create a standard build project for our product so I can run it on any Mac using just one script.
so I have exported all my distribution certificates into a p12 file which I store in my repository. during the build I import it using these commands

```
echo "Attaching External Keychain"
/usr/bin/openssl pkcs12 -in Distribution-Keys.p12 -nokeys -passin pass:<PASSWORD> | /usr/bin/openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -subject -dates -nameopt utf8,sep_semi_plus_space

echo "Creating external Keychain"
security create-keychain -p <PASSWORD> Distribution-Keys.keychain

echo "Changing access to external Keychain"
security set-keychain-settings -lut 21600 Distribution-Keys.keychain

echo "Unlocking external Keychain"
security unlock-keychain -p <PASSWORD> Distribution-Keys.keychain

echo "Importing external Keychain from p12 file"
security import Distribution-Keys.p12 -P <PASSWORD> -A -t cert -f pkcs12 -k Distribution-Keys.keychain


security list-keychain -d user

echo "Adding new keychain to search path"
security list-keychain -d user -s Distribution-Keys.keychain /Users/support/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db

security list-keychain -d user
```

when I run build script from ssh I get an "codesign" exited with code 3

when I run in a Mac terminal it pops up a window saying "codesign wants to access key 'Distribution-Keys' in your keychain
and asks for a password.

how would I allow the trust as a part of the script (command line) ?

Regards Christian Arild Stœr Andersen

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

The following command bypasses the codesign modal keychain password dialog:

```
security set-key-partition-list \
  -S apple-tool:,apple: \
  -k "$MAC_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD" \
  "$MAC_KEYCHAIN_PATH"
```

The following lines are pasted from `man security` run on macOS 14.0:

```
set-key-partition-list [-S <partition list (comma separated)>] [-k <keychain password>] [options...] [keychain] Sets the "partition list" for a key. The "partition list"
is an extra parameter in the ACL which limits access to the key based on an application's code signature. You must present the keychain's password to change a partition
list. If you'd like to run /usr/bin/codesign with the key, "apple:" must be an element of the partition list.

       -S partition-list
                       Comma-separated partition list. See output of "security dump-keychain" for examples.
       -k password     Password for keychain
       -a application-label
                       Match "application label" string
       -c creator      Match creator (four-character code)
       -d              Match keys that can decrypt
       -D description  Match "description" string
       -e              Match keys that can encrypt
       -j comment      Match comment string
       -l label        Match label string
       -r              Match keys that can derive
       -s              Match keys that can sign
       -t type         Type of key to find: one of "symmetric", "public", or "private"
       -u              Match keys that can unwrap
       -v              Match keys that can verify
       -w              Match keys that can wrap
```

See:

1. https://github.com/Apple-Actions/import-codesign-certs/blob/5565bb656f60c98c8fc515f3444dd8db73545dc2/src/security.ts#L121-L141